# Google Maps Crash GMSOverlayDisplayLayer

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having trouble tracking down a crash from Google maps. Does anyone have any methods I could use to try and profile this to find the issue? I am unable to replicate but users using older devices are having this at an alarming rate.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x182bbad8c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x181d745ec objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x182bc8098 __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 0x182bc05c8 ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x182aa641c _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  QuartzCore                     0x186d40f24 -[CALayer display]
6  mfa                            0x1006a4930 -[GMSOverlayLayer display]
7  QuartzCore                     0x186cb28f4 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
8  QuartzCore                     0x186cda364 CA::Transaction::commit()
9  QuartzCore                     0x186cdb1e4 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
10 CoreFoundation                 0x182b62910 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
11 CoreFoundation                 0x182b60238 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
12 CoreFoundation                 0x182b60884 __CFRunLoopRun
13 CoreFoundation                 0x182a80da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
14 GraphicsServices               0x184a65020 GSEventRunModal
15 UIKit                          0x18ca9d758 UIApplicationMain
16 mfa                            0x1002b1f98 main + 24 (AppDelegate.swift:24)
17 libdyld.dylib                  0x182511fc0 start
```

Comment: Is this crash only happening in older devices? How old are we talking? Does your app use the latest version (3.3.0) of Maps SDK for IOS, or an older one? And can you please share your code?

Comment: Latest version on app store is 3.1.0 I am submitting update today to bring it up to 3.3.0. I saw the change log for 3.2.0 had a fix for overlap layer removal crashes. I am hopeful this is the issue. I also made a modification to the user follow animation so rather than animating a Camera to follow a marker change 7 to 8 times a second I am just moving the camera with a GMSCameraUpdate. Will see if this resolves. Implementation is far to large to share on this platform.

Comment: Also the older devices are iPhone 7's and iPad Mini 4's or older. The app is also decoding h.264 (hardware decode) and also displaying in real time from a drone. The view is using OpenGL which I believe Google maps is for rendering on the same screen. Not sure if that has anything to do with it but it certainly is an high resource usage application.

Comment: Yep this is what I was thinking too, that it may be due to the crashes fixed in 3.2.0 but if this is not the case and your other code modifications don't work either please let us know and we'll investigate further.

Comment: @evan The update has been released for a week now. We went from 79% crash free users to 96% the issue had been the overlay bug fixed in 3.2.0. If you want to submit an answer to that effect for future users searching I will mark it as the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hey thanks for your update! Sure I'll post an answer to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug on crashes occurring when removing overlays that was reported in Google's Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130331383

The [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases) for Maps SDK for IOS confirm this is fixed in version 3.2.0.

> Version 3.2.0 - July 8, 2019
>
> Resolved Issues:
>
> - Fixed a crashing bug that occurred occasionally
>     when removing overlays from a map.

Updating to 3.2.0 or the latest version should resolve this issue.